# C++ if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm new to C++.
So I made this program that's supposed to be a password thingy. 
The problem is that when I input the correct password, which is "**bobby**", it goes straight to the **else** and not the **if**.

What is the problem ?

My Code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char password[] = "bobby";
char passinput[50];
char num[50];

top: 
cout << "Please enter your password: " << endl;
cin >> passinput;
if(passinput==password)
{
    cout << "Correct" << endl;
    cin >> num; 
}
else
{
    cout << "Incorrect, try again" << endl;
    goto top;
}
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: `goto` [considered harmful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful). Don't use it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: "Considered harmful" essays [considered harmful](http://meyerweb.com/eric/comment/chech.html). But yes, you rarely want `goto`, and you certainly don't want it here.

Comment: this question is marked as "c++" not "c", so you should better stick with c++ where possible: use std::string for storage, std::string::getline() for reading from stdin and generally no "go to".

Comment: `So I made this program that's supposed to be a password thingy.` That is hardly a technical description, is it...

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I think we should consider ""Considered harmful" essays considered harmful" essays harmful...

Answer (score 6):

Use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare c-style strings
Or use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) instead, since you mark the question c++:

```
string password("bobby");
string passinput;
string num;
```

Comment: +1 for recommending `std::string`. It may be useful to work out how `char*` works exactly sometime during the learning process, but in C++ you would hardly ever use that.

Comment: Whilst this might be a sensible suggestion, it doesn't actually answer the question, which is why the code doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

`if(passinput==password)` simply compares the starting addresses of two strings. Since both strings are at different location, the condition `passinput==password` evaluated as `false` and your `if` body is not executed.
To compare two c-style strings, you can use the `srtcmp` standard library function in `<string.h>`.

```
if(!strcmp(passinput,password)) //strcmp returns 0 if strings are equal. ! is used to make that 0 (false) to 1 (true)
{
    cout << "Correct" << endl;
    cin >> num; 
}
```

Comment: ahh, okay, but how do i use srtcmp? what do i do?

Comment: @EricLippert Such comments are best accompanied with [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: +1 since this is the only answer that explains why the comparison doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You should probably also explain why the ! is needed

Answer (score 2):

Use [string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) or `==` only when comparing the equality of C++ strings, otherwise you are only comparing the addresses of the two C-style strings.

To do this in C++, use

```
std::string password;
std::string passinput;
std::string num;

// if(password.compare(passinput) == 0) also would work
// but as noted in the comments, is overkill for what you
// are doing
if (password == passinput)
{
    cout << "Correct" << endl;
    cin >> num; 
}
else
{
    cout << "Incorrect, try again" << endl;
    goto top;
}
```

To do this in C (which is currently the style of string you are using), see @haccks answer.  For the sake of convenience, I've added the part of his answer that describes how to do this below.

To compare two C-style strings, you can use srtcmp standard library function in .

```
// strcmp(passinput, password) returns 0 for
// a successful match.  The ! (negation)
// converts 0 (false in c) to true
if(!strcmp(passinput,password))
{
    cout << "Correct" << endl;
    cin >> num; 
}
```

Comment: std::string has a valid overload for the equals operator ==

Comment: string::compare is overkill if you don't care which string is 'smaller'.

Comment: Using `.compare` is not incorrect, but I agree, it is not needed in this circumstance.  I've modified my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
if (strcmp (passinput,password) ==0)
{
...
}
```

strcmp returns 0 if strings are same, a value greater than zero when the first character that does not match has a greater value in first string than in second string and a value less than zerowhen its the opposite.

Include cstring/string.h